# Need help in counting strings under heads of Pandas data frame with timelines

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, string, dataframe

I am looking to count the frequency of each string under different heads in Pandas dataframe using Pandas pivot for data analysis with monthly trends. The data looks like below,

```
name    age  city        Date                  country   hight  MessageList  gender
Tom     10   NewYork       1/1/2021 08:35:58Z  US        NaN      X List      Male
Mark     5   London        5/1/2021 08:35:58Z  UK        NaN      X List      Male
Pam      7   London        3/6/2021 08:35:58Z  UK        NaN      Y List      Female
Tom     18   California    4/6/2021 08:35:58Z  US        163      Y List      Male
Lena    23   NewYork     12/12/2020 08:35:58Z  US        NaN      Y List      Female
Ben     17   Colombo     11/12/2020 08:35:58Z  Srilanka  NaN      X List      Male
Lena    23   Paris         8/1/2020 08:35:58Z  France    NaN      Y List      Female
Ben     51   Colombo       7/1/2020 08:35:58Z  Srilanka  NaN      Z List      Male
Tom     18   Paris         1/1/2021 08:35:58Z  France    NaN      Z List      Male
Mark     5   Paris         5/1/2021 08:35:58Z  Japan     NaN      Z List      Male
Tom     18   London        3/6/2021 08:35:58Z  UK        NaN      X List      Male
Tom     18   Paris         4/6/2021 08:35:58Z  France    163      Z List      Male

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='name', index=['name', 'city'],
                       aggfunc=np.count_nonzero())
```

I am new to Pandas and am struggling to get the string count with the monthly trend.

I am looking for output like this,

```
            2020         2021
Name        Nov   Dec    Jan    Feb
Tom
 Paris      3     1      2      3
 Colombo    2     3             3
 London     4     1      4      2
Mark
 Colombo    1            3      1
 London     3     3      2      2
Pam
 California 3     1             1
 NewYork    1            4      2
Len
 London     1     2      2      1
```

Comment: Please remember you can vote on answers that are helpful to you. You can see [Why is voting important?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: [New York](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City), [height](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/height#Noun), and [Sri Lanka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sri_Lanka) are misspelled (as *"NewYork"*, *"hight"*, and *"Srilanka"*, respectively). Aren't spaces allowed, e.g. by presuming TAB-separated fields? The capitalisation of the headers is inconsistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with months periods by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html), so possible create `MultiIndex` in ouput by [`PeriodIndex.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.year.html) with [`PeriodIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.strftime.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
table = pd.crosstab([df['name'], df['city']], df['Date'].dt.to_period('m'))

table.columns = [table.columns.year, table.columns.strftime('%b')]

print (table)
Date            2020             2021            
Date             Jul Aug Nov Dec  Jan Mar Apr May
name city                                        
Ben  Colombo       1   0   1   0    0   0   0   0
Lena NewYork       0   0   0   1    0   0   0   0
     Paris         0   1   0   0    0   0   0   0
Mark London        0   0   0   0    0   0   0   1
     Paris         0   0   0   0    0   0   0   1
Pam  London        0   0   0   0    0   1   0   0
Tom  California    0   0   0   0    0   0   1   0
     London        0   0   0   0    0   1   0   0
     NewYork       0   0   0   0    1   0   0   0
     Paris         0   0   0   0    1   0   1   0
```

Comment: I am getting KeyError: 'CNTRY LIST'

Comment: @Sherlock - What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: @Sherlock - Maybe some typo, whitespace in column names

Comment: record, entity, text_info, contact, alert_state, trn_status, name, address, address_1', address_2, Item_type, date, content

Comment: @Sherlock - hmm, if output from `print (df.columns.tolist())` then missing `[], ''` is possible show exaclty ouput from it?

Comment: any suggestions on getting the aggregate and plot it against the time lines